# PureScript does not compose `trace` and `show`

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, purescript

So the following works

```
 main = do
    trace $ show $ 5
```

but this does not

```
 main = do
    (trace . show) 5
```

in psci the type of trace is

```
 forall r. Prim.String -> Control.Monad.Eff.Eff (trace :: Debug.Trace.Trace | r) Prelude.Unit
```

and the type of show is

```
 forall a. (Prelude.Show a) => a -> Prim.String
```

since the return value of show is `Prim.String` and the first input into trace is `Prim.String` they should be composable. This is further evidenced by that `trace $ show` passes the type checking. But instead I get this error:

```
Error at  line 1, column 10: 
Error in declaration it
Cannot unify Prim.Object with Prim.Function Prim.String.
```

What am I missing here? Right now my mental model is that `trace` is very like `putStrLn` in Haskell, and that one can definitely be composed with `show`. `(putStrLn . show) 5` works.

Expected type of composed result of trace and show:

```
 forall a r. (Prelude.Show a) => a -> Control.Monad.Eff.Eff (trace :: Debug.Trace.Trace | r) Prelude.Unit
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` isn't function composition, but [property access](http://purescript.readthedocs.org/en/latest/syntax.html#property-accessors) in PureScript, as can be seen via

```
main = show $ { test : "Hello, string property" } . test
```

The function composition operator is called `<<<`, probably after the [same operator in `Control.Arrow` (Haskell)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-60--60--60-).

Comment: What is standard composition then?

Comment: @Fresheyeball: Haven't found any in the documentation. You can write one yourself, but the compiled JavaScript seems overly complicated.

Comment: I would rather not, it really belongs in the Prelude.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: \*sigh\*, it's not in the documentation, but I found it in [an issue](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/issues/358). It also has a flipped variant `>>>` with `f >>> g = \x -> g (f (x))`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to create an issue to get this documented.